# postgres with docker compose gives FATAL: role "root" does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a simple demo with postgres on a local windows machine with docker desktop.
This is my yaml docker compose file named `img.yaml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

    postgres-demo:
      image: postgres:11.5-alpine
      container_name: postgres-demo
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Welcome
        - POSTGRES_DB=conference_app
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      volumes:
        - .:/var/lib/my_data
      restart: always
```

I'm running it using the command:
`docker-compose -f img.yaml up`
And get the following output:

```
Starting postgres-demo ... done
Attaching to postgres-demo
postgres-demo    | 2020-02-12 17:07:46.487 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres-demo    | 2020-02-12 17:07:46.487 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres-demo    | 2020-02-12 17:07:46.508 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-demo    | 2020-02-12 17:07:46.543 UTC [18] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-12 17:07:10 UTC
postgres-demo    | 2020-02-12 17:07:46.556 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

And then, opening bash into the container with the command:
`docker exec -it d47056217a97 bash`
I want to watch the databases in container so I run in the bash the command:
`psql \dt`
And get the error:
`psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`.
Trying to create the database using the command: `psql> create database conference_app;` gives the error: `psql: FATAL:  role "conference_app" does not exist`.
I'm puzzled. What am I doing wrong? Is my yaml missing something?

Answer (score 133):

If you don’t specify the `PGUSER` environment variable, then `psql` will assume you want to use the current OS user as your database user name. In this case, you are using `root` as your OS user, and you will attempt to log in as `root`, but that user doesn’t exist in the database.

You’ll need to either call `psql -U postgres`, or `su - Postgres` first

See also the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-USER)

UPDATE: Someone suggested changing `PGUSER` to `POSTGRES_USER` -- this is actually incorrect.  Postgres looks for `PGUSER` in the environment, but if you're using Docker, you'll tell Docker the correct user by using `POSTGRES_USER`, which gets assigned to `PGUSER` -- see the [entrypoint source code](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/44ef8b226a40f86cf9df3f9299067db6779a3aa3/docker-entrypoint.sh#L272)

Comment: I managed to do it not from the image bash but with the command: docker exec -it postgres-demo psql -U postgres -d conference_app -f /var/lib/my_data/insert_data.sql

Comment: I used it like this:
`environment:

      PGUSER: postgres`
and it worked for me.

Answer (score 38):

I specified `user: postgres` for the service in docker-compose file. Then deleted the existing container to re-spin it with the next `docker-compose up` execution. Container came up with the user "postgres", so you just need `psql -l` from there onwards(don't need -U flag)

This was my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.6-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: postgres12_6
    user: postgres
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m"
    networks:
      - esnet
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

networks:
  esnet:
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the most simple to understand . Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If you also specify a database other than the default you should also include this in the `pg_ready` cmd eg:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d db-name -U db-user"]
```

In the above snippet my db name is `db-name` and using a user `db-user`.
I needed to specify this despite also setting the `POSTGRES_DB` & `POSTGRES_USER` env vars.

Answer (score 18):

The container assumes that you are trying to connect to db with root user(current user) since you dont specify the user and database name on docker exec.

**Following should work:**

```
docker exec -it <container_id/container_name> psql -U <user_name> <database_name>
docker exec -it d47056217a97 psql -U postgres conference_app
```

Comment: I had a custom username set but when I called:
`docker exec -it postgres psql -U <custom_username>`

I was getting the error: 
`psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: database "<custom_username>" does not exist`
Once I specified the <database_name> it worked!

Answer (score 11):

As richyen [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194261/4554883), you need to set the `PGUSER` environment variable, even if you have already set the `POSTGRES_USER` variable. This is simply because `psql` and `pg_isready` are two different (although related) programs which have different logic of environment lookup (one looks for `POSTGRES_USER`, the other one – for `PGUSER`).

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: me
      PGUSER: me
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready
```

If you want to only rely on one variable and don't want to "plug holes" with your database username, you can put the value of `POSTGRES_USER` directly in the healthcheck `test` command:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: me
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U $$POSTGRES_USER
```

Note how `$$POSTGRES_USER` is prefixed with two dollar signs; that's intentional.

After that you'll probably want to also add `-d db` option as per Christopher Peisert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76757417/4554883).

Comment: Why is the double dollar prefix required? I also tested this, and the `test: pg_isready...` worked but `test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", ...]` didn't. Do you know why that is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ogaday The `$$` sign is an escaping mechanism. If you write `-U $$POSTGRES_USER`, the actual command that actually runs in the actual container is `pg_isready -U $POSTGRES_USER`: the environment that was set during `docker compose up` is then read by the container's terminal. If instead you write `-U $POSTGRES_USER`, the variable is read from your host computer environment and substituted by Docker itself during `docker compose up`. The resulting string (whatever it is) is eventually (when the container starts) going to be run as a command.

Answer (score 7):

## Update for docker-compose v2+

### Error 1 - FATAL: role "root" does not exist

As stated in [richyen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194261/1164465), set the `PGUSER` environment variable.

NOTE: `POSTGRES_USER` by itself will not work.

### Error 2 - FATAL: database "X" does not exist

In this case, `X` is usually the value of the `PGUSER` environment variable.

After setting the `PGUSER` environment variable, it fixes the original error, but introduces a new error:

> FATAL: database "X" does not exist

#### Solution

The fix is to define the database host as its own Docker network IP address as in:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready -h db"
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

Here the `-h db` refers to the `db` service's own Docker IP address. With this configuration, there is often no need to pass additional flags to [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html).

Comment: For anyone wondering where to set this environment variable. Even though i already set `POSTGRES_USER`, i also needed to set `PGUSER` in my 
docker-compose.yml for the postgres container.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I was using windows 10, I tried everything I could but still not works.

finally, I removed all the related docker image, docker container, local host folder, and restart windows.

and everything goes well

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove volume as I run docker-compose with variables which I later changed

```
POSTGRES_USER=
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
POSTGRES_DB=
```