# Why does `pg_isready` not respect database option?

Tags: postgresql

When I run `pg_isready` with database option, I always get response that everything is ok:

```
pg_isready -h pgdb -U pdnsdf -d askldfjkasdjf
pgdb:5432 - accepting connections
```

Here database does not exists. So I expect it is not ready.

Why does `pg_isready` not respect database option?

Comment: Please note, that when server in *initdb* mode the `pg_isready` will return true, because actually server is up. If you want to check that an initialized server is ready [you can leverage the fact](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#initialization-scripts) that during *initdb* server is available via socket only. Thus add `-h localhost` option to check the server was initialized and ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html)

> It is not necessary to supply correct user name, password, or database name values to obtain the server status; however, if incorrect values are provided, the server will log a failed connection attempt.

If you want to see the error, you have to check the log file of the server.

> Here database does not exists. So I expect it is not ready.

`pg_isready` checks if the *server* (instance, cluster, ..) is ready to accept connections. It is not intended to check if a specific database (or user or table) inside that cluster exists.

Comment: So what serves that options for?

Comment: The options are there because you may have multiple instances(clusters) of Postgres  running on different ports and hosts. As to the database and user names they are not needed, but folks include them as they can show up in the logs and therefore be useful to track what software/person initiated the check.