# Postgres docker container is always being reported as unhealthy in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to add a health check for my docker as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72175755/785523). My docker compose looks like below

```
version: '3'
services:
  # IMPORTANT NOTE: All other services will share the network on pgadmin service (network_mode: "service:pgadmin"), so ports need to be opened here instead of other the services.
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "6555:80"       # pg admin
      - "6432:6432"     # postgres-db
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin

  postgres-db:
    container_name: test-db
    image: postgres:14.4
    network_mode: "service:pgadmin"
    command: -p 6432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
```

But the Postgres container is being reported as unhealthy.

```
debrajmanna@debrajmanna-DX6QR261G3 java % docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                                   NAMES
fec13f7d67e3   postgres:14.4    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 seconds ago   Up 16 seconds (unhealthy)                                                           test-db
b4042b8e906b   dpage/pgadmin4   "/entrypoint.sh"         17 seconds ago   Up 16 seconds               443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6432->6432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6555->80/tcp   pgadmin
```

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to add `-p 6432` in the health check. The working docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "6555:80"       # pg admin
      - "6432:6432"     # postgres-db
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin

  postgres-db:
    # Postgres version should be compatible with Aurora:
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.20180305.html
    container_name: test-db
    image: postgres:14.4
    network_mode: "service:pgadmin"
    command: -p 6432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGUSER: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -p 6432"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
```

The reason for adding `PGUSER` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194261/785523).

Answer (score -2):

try this for postgres-db:
*command: postgres -p 6432*

It seems to me here is a mistake.

Comment: No does not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).