# Peer authentication failed with docker and postgreSQL / Mac OS / Python

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, authentication, gis

I have to create a spatial PostgreSQL database with Docker ans I have the following problem :

System : macOS Catalina, version 10.15.7
docker v.20.10
Python v.3.7.7
postgreSQL v.13.1 install with Brew

I enter this in my terminal to create a PostgreSQL server listening on the 5432 port with docker.

```
 docker run --name=postgis -d -e POSTGRES_PASS=123456789 -p 5432:5432 kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4`
```

Then:

```
`docker exec -it postgis bash`
```

it contained the following elements : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VabD.png

Then I tried to access the database :

```
psql -U postgres
```

I've got this message : `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

When I inspect the logs in docker I see this :

```
 postgres@postgres DETAIL: Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 85: "local all postgres peer"
```

I open the pg_hba.conf with Sublime Text in usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba_conf

But all methods were TRUST and line 85 was different. I still modified by putting md5 everywhere. Then I did the following command:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

I repeated but always the same error message and the same sentence when inspecting the logs.

It seems that my postgreSQL uses another file than the pg_hba.conf I see, yet I can't find anything else.

thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the issue is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60193781/postgres-with-docker-compose-gives-fatal-role-root-does-not-exist-error/60194261#60194261, except you're encountering this with `postgres` user instead of `root` user

Comment: I have the same issue with the `kartoza/postgis` docker image...did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `psql -U postgres -W` to make PostgreSQL ask you for password.